# Where Windows stores Internet Options?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, regedit

I'm trying to find where in Regedit Windows stores the security settings available on 'Internet Options', specially the one at Miscellaneous > Display mixed content.

That's because i have an app that uses Internet Explorer and some of this settings cause problems , so i'd like to offer an option to auto-setup the options.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft, it's stored in HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\XXX

*(where XXX is the current zone ID as mapped via ZoneMap)*

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182569

In this key are several DWORD values given by a numeric ID.  "**Display mixed content**" is value ID **1609**.

Also according to that page:

> Note: Unless stated otherwise, each DWORD value is equal to zero, one,
>   or three. Typically, a setting of zero sets a specific action as
>   permitted, a setting of one causes a prompt to appear, and a setting
>   of three prohibits the specific action.

Answer (score 4):

#### Internet Explorer security zones registry entries for advanced users

> **Internet Explorer 5.0 and later versions of Internet Explorer**
>
> Internet Explorer security zones settings are stored under the
>   following registry subkeys:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
> ```
>
> These registry keys contain the following keys:
>
> ```
> TemplatePolicies
> ZoneMap
> Zones
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> By default, security zones settings are stored in the
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry subtree. Because this subtree is
>   dynamically loaded for each user, the settings for one user do not
>   affect the settings for another.
>
> If the Security Zones use only machine settings setting in Group Policy is enabled, or if
>   the Security_HKLM_only DWORD value is present and has a value of 1 in
>   the following registry subkey, only local computer settings are used
>   and all users have the same security settings:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
> ```
>
> With the Security_HKLM_only policy enabled, HKLM values will be used
>   by Internet Explorer. However, the HKCU values will still be displayed
>   in the zone settings on the Security tab in Internet Explorer. In
>   Internet Explorer 7, the Security tab of the Internet Options dialog
>   box displays the following message to indicate that settings are
>   managed by the system administrator:
>
> ```
> Some settings are managed by your system administrator
> ```
>
> If the Security Zones use only machine settings setting is not enabled in Group Policy, or
>   if the Security_HKLM_only DWORD value does not exist or is set to 0,
>   computer settings are used together with user settings. However, only
>   user settings appear in the Internet Options.
>
> For example, when this DWORD value does not exist or is set to 0,
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` settings are read together with
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` settings, but only `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` settings
>   appear in the Internet Options.
>
> **TemplatePolicies**
>
> The `TemplatePolicies` key determines the settings of the default
>   security zone levels. These levels are Low, Medium Low, Medium, and
>   High. You can change the security level settings from the default
>   settings. However, you cannot add more security levels. The keys
>   contain values that determine the setting for the security zone. Each
>   key contains a Description string value and a Display Name string
>   value that determine the text that appears on the Security tab for
>   each security level.
>
> **ZoneMap**
>
> The ZoneMap key contains the following keys:
>
> ```
> Domains
> EscDomains
> ProtocolDefaults
> Ranges
> ```
>
> The Domains key contains domains and protocols that have been added to
>   change their behavior from the default behavior. When a domain is
>   added, a key is added to the Domains key. Subdomains appear as keys
>   under the domain where they belong. Each key that lists a domain
>   contains a DWORD with a value name of the affected protocol. The value
>   of the DWORD is the same as the numeric value of the security zone
>   where the domain is added.
>
> The EscDomains key resembles the Domains key except that the
>   EscDomains key applies to those protocols that are affected by the
>   Enhanced Security Configuration (ESC). ESC is introduced in Microsoft
>   Windows Server 2003.
>
> The ProtocolDefaults key specifies the default security zone that is
>   used for a particular protocol (ftp, http, https). To change the
>   default setting, you can either add a protocol to a security zone by
>   clicking Add Sites on the Security tab, or you can add a DWORD value
>   under the Domains key. The name of the DWORD value must match the
>   protocol name, and it must not contain any colons (:) or slashes (/).
>
> The ProtocolDefaults key also contains DWORD values that specify the
>   default security zones where a protocol is used. You cannot use the
>   controls on the Security tab to change these values. This setting is
>   used when a particular Web site does not fall in a security zone.
>
> The Ranges key contains ranges of TCP/IP addresses. Each TCP/IP range
>   that you specify appears in an arbitrarily named key. This key
>   contains a :Range string value that contains the specified TCP/IP
>   range. For each protocol, a DWORD value is added that contains the
>   numeric value of the security zone for the specified IP range.
>
> When the Urlmon.dll file uses the MapUrlToZone public function to
>   resolve a particular URL to a security zone, it uses one of the
>   following methods:
>
> - If the URL contains a fully qualified domain name (FQDN), the
>     Domains
>     key is processed.
> - In this method, an exact site match overrides a random match.
>     If the URL contains an IP address, the
>     Ranges
>     key is processed. The IP address of the URL is compared to the :Range value that is contained in the arbitrarily named keys under the
>     Ranges key.
>
> Note:
>
> Because arbitrarily named keys are processed in the order that they
>   were added to the registry, this method may find a random match before
>   it finds a match. If this method does find a random match first, the
>   URL may be executed in a different security zone than the zone where
>   it is typically assigned. This behavior is by design.
>
> **Zones**
>
> Note:
>
> By default, starting with Windows XP SP2, the Local Machine Zone is
>   locked down to help improve security. For more information, click the
>   following article number to view the article in the Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base: 922704 Information about some new Group Policy
>   settings for Internet Explorer Security Zones in Microsoft Windows XP
>   Service Pack 2 and in Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 For
>   more information, visit the following Microsoft Web site:
>   http://technet2.microsoft.com/windowsserver/en/library/aebcfc94-25d5-4f41-93cc-7fb6e031de401033.mspx?mfr=true
>
> The Zones key contains keys that represent each security zone that is
>   defined for the computer. By default, the following five zones are
>   defined (numbered zero through four):
>
> ```
>    Value    Setting
>    ------------------------------
>    0        My Computer
>    1        Local Intranet Zone
>    2        Trusted sites Zone
>    3        Internet Zone
>    4        Restricted Sites Zone
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> By default, My Computer does not appear in the Zone box on the
>   Security tab.
>
> Each of these keys contains the following DWORD values that represent
>   corresponding settings on the custom Security tab.
>
> Note:
>
> Unless stated otherwise, each DWORD value is equal to zero, one, or
>   three. Typically, a setting of zero sets a specific action as
>   permitted, a setting of one causes a prompt to appear, and a setting
>   of three prohibits the specific action.
>
> ```
> Value    Setting
> 1001     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Download signed ActiveX controls
> 1004     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Download unsigned ActiveX controls
> 1200     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins
> 1201     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting
> 1206     Miscellaneous: Allow scripting of Internet Explorer Web browser control ^
> 1207     Reserved #
> 1208     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Allow previously unused ActiveX controls to run without prompt ^
> 1209     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Allow Scriptlets
> 120A     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Override Per-Site (domain-based) ActiveX restrictions
> 120B     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Override Per-Site (domain-based) ActiveX restrictions
> 1400     Scripting: Active scripting
> 1402     Scripting: Scripting of Java applets
> 1405     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Script ActiveX controls marked as safe for scripting
> 1406     Miscellaneous: Access data sources across domains
> 1407     Scripting: Allow Programmatic clipboard access
> 1408     Reserved #
> 1409     Scripting: Enable XSS Filter
> 1601     Miscellaneous: Submit non-encrypted form data
> 1604     Downloads: Font download
> 1605     Run Java #
> 1606     Miscellaneous: Userdata persistence ^
> 1607     Miscellaneous: Navigate sub-frames across different domains
> 1608     Miscellaneous: Allow META REFRESH * ^
> 1609     Miscellaneous: Display mixed content *
> 160A     Miscellaneous: Include local directory path when uploading files to a server ^
> 1800     Miscellaneous: Installation of desktop items
> 1802     Miscellaneous: Drag and drop or copy and paste files
> 1803     Downloads: File Download ^
> 1804     Miscellaneous: Launching programs and files in an IFRAME
> 1805     Launching programs and files in webview #
> 1806     Miscellaneous: Launching applications and unsafe files
> 1807     Reserved ** #
> 1808     Reserved ** #
> 1809     Miscellaneous: Use Pop-up Blocker ** ^
> 180A     Reserved # 
> 180B     Reserved #
> 180C     Reserved #
> 180D     Reserved #
> 180E     Allow OpenSearch queries in Windows Explorer #
> 180F     Allow previewing and custom thumbnails of OpenSearch query results in Windows Explorer #
> 1A00     User Authentication: Logon
> 1A02     Allow persistent cookies that are stored on your computer #
> 1A03     Allow per-session cookies (not stored) #
> 1A04     Miscellaneous: Don't prompt for client certificate selection when no 
>                        certificates or only one certificate exists * ^
> 1A05     Allow 3rd party persistent cookies *
> 1A06     Allow 3rd party session cookies *
> 1A10     Privacy Settings *
> 1C00     Java permissions #
> 1E05     Miscellaneous: Software channel permissions
> 1F00     Reserved ** #
> 2000     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Binary and script behaviors
> 2001     .NET Framework-reliant components: Run components signed with Authenticode
> 2004     .NET Framework-reliant components: Run components not signed with Authenticode
> 2007     .NET Framework-Reliant Components: Permissions for Components with Manifests
> 2100     Miscellaneous: Open files based on content, not file extension ** ^
> 2101     Miscellaneous: Web sites in less privileged web content zone can navigate into this zone **
> 2102     Miscellaneous: Allow script initiated windows without size or position constraints ** ^
> 2103     Scripting: Allow status bar updates via script ^
> 2104     Miscellaneous: Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars ^
> 2105     Scripting: Allow websites to prompt for information using scripted windows ^
> 2200     Downloads: Automatic prompting for file downloads ** ^
> 2201     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Automatic prompting for ActiveX controls ** ^
> 2300     Miscellaneous: Allow web pages to use restricted protocols for active content **
> 2301     Miscellaneous: Use Phishing Filter ^
> 2400     .NET Framework: XAML browser applications
> 2401     .NET Framework: XPS documents
> 2402     .NET Framework: Loose XAML
> 2500     Turn on Protected Mode [Vista only setting] #
> 2600     Enable .NET Framework setup ^
> 2702     ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Allow ActiveX Filtering
> 2708     Miscellaneous: Allow dragging of content between domains into the same window
> 2709     Miscellaneous: Allow dragging of content between domains into separate windows
> 270B     Miscellaneous: Render legacy filters
> 270C     ActiveX Controls and plug-ins: Run Antimalware software on ActiveX controls 
>
>
> {AEBA21FA-782A-4A90-978D-B72164C80120}   First Party Cookie *
> {A8A88C49-5EB2-4990-A1A2-0876022C854F}   Third Party Cookie *
> ```
>
> - `*`  indicates an Internet Explorer 6 or later setting
> - `**` indicates a Windows XP Service Pack 2 or later setting
> - `#`  indicates a setting that is not displayed in the user interface in Internet Explorer
> - `^`  indicates a setting that only has two options, enabled or disabled

Source [Internet Explorer security zones registry entries for advanced users](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182569)

Comment: Hmm, this is a copy/paste of the link contents that I answered with a full 13 minutes before your answer.  Congrats on winning the points, I guess.

Comment: @psouza4 Sorry, i did not notice you answered before, just changed the credit. Both were of great help, thanks !

Comment: @psouza4 We started at the same time. It takes longer to produce a comprehensive answer. Anyway I upvoted your answer ... ;)